# How to set instance variables in a class based view?

Tags: python, django

I want to check if a user is in a specific group on initilisation of the class based view.

Then use that variable in a number of methods like `get_form()`and `get_context_data()`

However I get an error:

```
File "/projects/hr_project/entries/views.py", line 117, in get_form_class
    if self.is_manager:
AttributeError: 'EntryCreateView' object has no attribute 'is_manager'
```

Here is the class based view:

```
class EntryCreateView(
        LoginRequiredMixin,
        FormView,
        MessagePermissionRequiredMixin,):
    '''Class based view to enter new timesheet entries
    '''
    form_class = None
    template_name = 'entries/entry_form.html'
    permission_required = None
    permission_denied_message = 'You do not have the permission to create an entry for that user'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Initialise variables and check permissions once
        # Set the intial date
        if self.kwargs.get('date'):
            self.date = self.kwargs.get('date')
        else:
            self.date = self.get_form().fields['date'].initial

        self.date = str(self.date)
        self.date_val = datetime.strptime(self.date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        self.is_manager = False
        manager_group = Group.objects.get(name='Managers')
        if manager_group in request.user.groups.all():
            self.is_manager = True

        # Set the user and permission
        self.permission = True
        self.user = request.user
        if self.is_manager:
            # Check user is manager
            self.user = self.kwargs.get('user')
        else:
            if self.kwargs.get('user') == request.user.id:
                self.user = self.kwargs.get('user')
            else:
                self.permission = False
        super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def has_permission(self):
        ''''Override how permissions are checked
        '''
        return self.permission

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context_data = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        return context_data
```

Comment: Can you show how, EntryCreateView looks like?

Comment: If you set `self.is_manager = False` in dispatch, then you should be able to access `self.is_manager` in `get_form_class`. If you're getting an attribute error, it suggests that `self.is_manager = False` did not run in your actual code. Your example code doesn't make sense, since the dispatch method doesn't return anything.

Comment: Please show the full view.

Comment: Apologies for the late update. I have added the entire class now.

Comment: Ah, thank you @Alasdair. The call to `self.get_form()` is made in the `dispatch` method. That is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think it’s a very good design to call `get_form` in your `dispatch` method - it already runs when you call `super()` so you are running the method twice.

If you do stick with this approach, you have to reorder your code. Currently you are trying to read `self.is_manager` when you call `get_form()`, but you don’t set the attribute until later in your `dispatch` method.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret that correctly, your problem is that `is_manager` is not available on the instances of your objects.

If `is_manager` is being declared as an instance variable in the `dispatch` method, it only gets set on an instance of that class when you call this specific method on it.

If you create an object `a` of your class, then perform an `a.dispatch(your_arguments)` you should be able to access `a.is_manager` properly.

Usually if you want your class to have instance variables, you do it in your classe's `__init__` function, e.g:

```
class Test:
  def __init__(self):
    self.is_manager = False
```

Hope that helps.